# Manual TRIM Windows 7 on OCZ VERTEX 2 SATA II 2.5" SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, trim

I have an OCZ VERTEX 2 SATA II 2.5" SSD with Windows 7 Professional installed on it. I am pretty sure TRIM is not working because my motherboard is the Asus M2N-SLI (not the Deluxe model) which does not support AHCI mode for the drive. Is there a utility that is compatible with this drive that I could possibly run once a day that would do something similar to a manual TRIM in order to keep the drive performance up? I could not find one specifically for this drive on the OCZ website.

I did find a User-Initiated Garbage Collection wiper tool, but it is for a Vertex drive not Vertex 2. I tried to run it, but it said that wiper could not be run for all the drives on this system.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need AHCI mode for TRIM to work. It works in IDe mode as well. What you need to do is use Microsofts own IDE storage drivers instead of the Nvidia drivers. Then you will have TRIM.

Comment: Is my drive in IDE mode, is that the only other possibility? How do I change the driver to use Microsoft's IDE storage driver?